# how do I dispatch the functions that generated by halide (tutorial lesson 15)?

Tags: halide

The tutorial generates 3 functions with different target and pack into a single static library along with halide runtime.

The question is, how do I call it ?
To my understanding, I should check the cpu feature before calling the functions.
What is the best way the dispatch these functions ?

```
./lesson_15_generate \
    -g my_first_generator \
    -f my_first_generator_basic \
    -e object,c_header\
    -o . \
    target=host-x86-64-no_runtime

./lesson_15_generate \
    -g my_first_generator \
    -f my_first_generator_sse41 \
    -e object,c_header\
    -o . \
    target=host-x86-64-sse41-no_runtime

./lesson_15_generate \
    -g my_first_generator \
    -f my_first_generator_avx \
    -e object,c_header\
    -o . \
    target=host-x86-64-avx-no_runtime
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get Halide to do the dispatch for you at runtime using a comma-separated list of targets:

```
./lesson_15_generate \
    -g my_first_generator \
    -f my_first_generator \
    -e static_library,c_header\
    -o . \
    target=x86-64-avx-no_runtime,x86-64-sse41-no_runtime,x86-64-no_runtime
```

That makes it compile three different pieces of code for the three targets. Calling "my_first_generator" will then automatically dispatch to the first thing in the list that it thinks it can run, based on checking the CPU ID on the first call.

Comment: Error: (at ../tools/GenGen.cpp:4)
Cannot request object for compile_multitarget.
Aborted (core dumped), the method doesn't work on my system. my git HEAD is de5428ffc367 and compiled with llvm-1:11~++20200705063810 , [https://stackoverflow.com/users/3874652/andrew-adams]

Comment: Oops, edited my reply to say "static_library" instead of "object"